# evitar quebra de linha dentro de uma tabela, ou tamanho mínimo

Tags: html, css

Galera e possível determinar um tamanho máximo e mínimo para um tabela?

O meu problema e o seguinte, tenho uma tabela com um texto dentro dela, e quando eu diminuo o tamanho da janela do navegar tudo vai ficando espremido dentro dela.

Toquei que o problema so ocorre se eu usar o width: 100%; pois se eu usar o width: 400px; o tabela não achata o seu conteúdo, porem gera uma barra de rolagem, e é exatamente isso que eu quero.

Bom segue o código simples da tabela. Se alguém souber alguma forma de me ajudar fico muito grato.

```css
.layout_geral_fixo {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background: #484848;
    z-index: 6;
    height: 37px;
}
```

```html
   <table class="layout_geral_fixo">
            <!-- Menu topo -->

            <tr>
                <td>
asasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasdasdasd

                </td>
            </tr>

            <!-- FIM Menu topo -->
        </table>
```

[código no jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9zecwuyt/2/)

Comment: já tentou `white-space: nowrap`? só não vai aparecer a famigerada barra de rolagem.

Comment: já sim, so não sei se eu fiz de forma correta, tem com vc fazer um exemplo no meu código? postei ele no link

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9zecwuyt/3/

Comment: em todo caso, antes de continuar utilizando tables para montar o seu layout, leia isto: https://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/everything.html

Comment: funcionou, então para layout eu sempre uso div e css, porém como se trata de um layout simples de relatório eu prefiro usar a tabela

Comment: como posso usar o white_space em div? olha o menu que montei:https://jsfiddle.net/9zecwuyt/4/

Comment: **Uma dica:** Coloque sempre o código dentro da pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente usar este:

```
table {
 table-layout:fixed;
 width:100%;
 border:1px solid #f00;
 word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Comment: Favor, não utilize **tente** em resposta, o correto é comentar quando não se tem a certeza de que funciona. Agora se tem a plena certeza, explique ao **AP** sua resposta.

Answer (score 3):

Para evitar quebra  de linha em tabela use `white-space: nowrap;`.

No css externo:

```
.classDaSuaTRouTD{

   white-space: nowrap;

}
```

No css *inline*:

```
style= "white-space: nowrap;
```

Quanto a definir o tamanho mínimo você pode por classes nas `<tr>` e nas `<td>` definindo via css a largura e altura delas, mas usando apenas o `white-space: nowrap;` a palavra já se adequa a sua *table*.

OBS: coloque o código  na tr ou td aonde está ocorrendo a quebra de linha

Comment: ok e como posso fazer isso em uma div? olha so o meu que montei, ele apresenta quebra de linha dentro da div. https://jsfiddle.net/9zecwuyt/4/

Comment: Amigo será que usar a tag <a> apenas é a melhor solução, pelo que notei parece ser um menu, tente usar lista, pode resolver seu problema colocando ela inline

Comment: poderia me dar um exemplo de com fazer de forma correta?

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que possa usar 2 parametros,um para definir o minimo e o outro para o maximo de largura:

```
div.umaclasse {
min-width:100px;
max-width:200px;
}
```

Se colocar o parametro `min-width` quando a tela diminuir a sua div irá diminuir junto,porém se chegar a 100px não ira mais diminuir.E com o `max-width` a div não passaria de 200px.

Para poder ficar com a barra de rolagem podes usar o `overflow` para definir se ira aparecer:

```
div.umaclasse {
max-width:100px;       /*esta div tem muito conteudo para apenas 100px*/
overflow:scroll;       /*com isso a barra de rolagem estará sempre habiltada,mas se deixar auto a barra só aparecece se necessário*/
}
```

No seu código poderia ficar assim:

```
.layout_geral_fixo {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background: #484848;
    z-index: 6;
    height: 37px;
    min-width:100px;/*valor minimo px,cm,% etc.*/;
    max-width:200px;/*valor maximo px,,cm,% etc.*/;
    overflow:scroll/*valores:auto,hidden,visible,scroll*/;
}
```

Pra falar a verdade ésta é minha primeira resposta,então se tiver qualquer erro comente,caso não responda a pergunta ignore(e marque negativo Y-Y).